# Can't see images in Media Library in Wordpress (Localhost)?

Tags: php, wordpress, image, file-upload, localhost

I am developing my website on localhost (WordPress version 4.9.3.2) right now and whenever I switch to any default theme like twentyfourteen, I am very much able to upload and view images in Media Library, but whenever I am on my own theme, neither am I able to view any images, nor upload.

The errors are as follows -

1. Can't upload featured image.
2. Can't upload any image through post.
3. Can't see any images in media library.
4. The images that I try to upload 'through' media library, get saved in the 'uploads' folder, so I know that my folder location is right, but even then I can't see them.
5. The images do not get saved in 'uploads' folder if I try to upload them through a post or anything, only through media library they get saved.

The solutions I tried -

1. I have not installed any plugins yet, so disabling/enabling one is out of the question.
2. I have increased the memory limit to 256M, nothing happened.
3. I have also tried installing wordpress again, nothing happened either.
4. I tried changing image-editor to default-GB in functions - nothing happened.

I don't know what I am doing wrong, but this has really frustrated me since over a week. If someone can help, it will really be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Too late, and hopefully you were able to solve this issue. However, this may help someone else.

I just faced the same problem, and in my case i was having an issue with a callback, here:

```
add_theme_support( 'custom-header', 
    apply_filters( 'ivana_custom_header_args', [
        'default-image' => '',
        'default-text-color' => '000',
        'width' => 1000,
        'height' => 250,
        'flex-width' => true,
        'flex-height' => true,
        'wp-head-callback' => [ $this, 'site_branding_style' ]
    ]; )
);
```

I'm organizing the code on an object oriented way, by following  [this architecture](https://github.com/Alecaddd/awps), but the callback ('wp-head-callback') wasn't being called correctly. In my case, it was into another class, and it was a private method, so i moved it into the same class where i am adding all theme support and making it a public method.

Setup.php

```
<?php
/**
 * @package ivana
 */

namespace Ivana\Setup;

use Ivana\Setup\CustomArguments;

class Setup
{
    private $custom_arguments;

    public function register()
    {
        $custom_arguments_instance = new CustomArguments();
        $this->custom_arguments = $custom_arguments_instance->start();

        add_action( 'after_setup_theme', [ $this, 'setup' ] );

        // Why isn't the setup function being
        // called? We don't (8)
        // echo '<pre>';
        //     var_dump( $this->custom_arguments['header'] );
        //     var_dump( $this->custom_arguments['background'] );
        //     var_dump( $this->custom_arguments['logo'] );
        // echo '</pre>';
    }

    public function setup()
    {
        // Uncomment this for multilingual theme.
        // Currentlly there is no support whatsoever for
        // multilingual theme.
        // load_theme_textdomain( 'ivana', get_template_directory() . '/languages' );

        // Uncomment this if using WooCommerce
        // add_theme_support( 'woocommerce' );

        add_theme_support( 'automatic-feed-links' );
        add_theme_support( 'title-tag' );
        add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
        add_theme_support( 'menus' );

        add_theme_support( 'html5', [
            'search-form',
            'comment-form',
            'comment-list',
            'gallery',
            'caption'
        ] );

        add_theme_support( 'custom-header', 
            apply_filters( 'ivana_custom_header_args', $this->custom_arguments['header'] )
        );

        add_theme_support( 'custom-background', 
            apply_filters( 'ivana_custom_background_args', $this->custom_arguments['background'] )
        );

        add_theme_support( 'custom-logo', 
            apply_filters( 'ivana_custom_logo_args', $this->custom_arguments['logo'] )
        );

        add_theme_support( 'post-formats', [
            'aside',
            'gallery',
            'link',
            'image',
            'quote',
            'status',
            'video',
            'audio',
            'chat'
        ] );
    }
}
```

CustomArguments.php

```
<?php
/**
 * @package ivana
 */

namespace Ivana\Setup;

class CustomArguments
{
    private $custom_arguments = [];

    public function start()
    {
        $this->custom_header_arguments();
        $this->custom_background_arguments();
        $this->custom_logo_arguments();

        return $this->custom_arguments;
    }

    private function custom_header_arguments()
    {
        $this->custom_arguments['header'] = [
            'default-image' => '',
            'default-text-color' => '000',
            'width' => 1000,
            'height' => 250,
            'flex-width' => true,
            'flex-height' => true,
            'wp-head-callback' => [ $this, 'site_branding_style' ]
        ];
    }

    private function custom_background_arguments()
    {
        $this->custom_arguments['background'] = [
            'default-color' => 'fff',
            'default-image' => ''
        ];
    }

    private function custom_logo_arguments()
    {
        $this->custom_arguments['logo'] = [
            'height' => 250,
            'width' => 250,
            'flex-height' => true,
            'flex-width' => true
        ];
    }

    public function site_branding_style()
    { ?>
        <style type="text/css">
            .site-title,
            .site-description {
                position: absolute;
                clip: rect(1px, 1px, 1px, 1px);
            }
        </style>
    <?php
    }
}
```

In any case, my way for debugging this was to start commenting out lines or entire files and reloading the media library. When i commented out everything inside setup, the images were correctly loading, so then i started commenting individual lines or functions, until the problem was found.